# Propagating 'trash' ASN, what happens?

Tags: bgp

This sounds crazy, but I'm analyzing the raw RIS BGP announcement dataset and I spot this announcement:

> BGP4MP|1543859911|A|198.32.125.181|51185|52.94.20.0/24|51185 9304 1161216244|INCOMPLETE|198.32.125.96|0|0||NAG||

This announcement is collected by **AS 51185**. Sometimes I spot the AS-path is 51185 following by a 'trash' ASN also, e.g.,

> 51185 1161216244

Is this **ASN 1161216244** even possible? If this ASN is possible, can you guess who is doing this practice and why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since 2007 and [RFC4893](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4893) AS Numbers can be 32 bits.

So 1161216244 is technically a valid AS number.

However according to [this IANA page](http://www.iana.org/assignments/as-numbers/as-numbers.xhtml) numbers between 399261 and 4199999999 are unallocated (and not reserved for private use).

So it seems somebody incorrectly used this number, maybe as a private AS number, and it was not filtered.

Comment: The RIS raw dataset seems to include all announcements received by all vantage points. The announcements that include these unallocated ASN are *recorded* by one single vantage point, but not accepted and propagated by any.